# Rotating un-symmetric groups about the group center while using kinetic js

Tags: kineticjs

I'm trying to rotate a group of 6 rec's about it center while using group.setOffset(x,y); 
with no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: put some code in a jsfiddle and I'll take a look at it.